# Selectively updating a jar from eclipse

Tags: java, jar, eclipse-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Updating .class file in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667153/updating-class-file-in-jar)

I want to selectively update an existing jar file (outside the workspace) adding/updating some .class files (scattered throughout the hierarchy in build folder) generated in my eclipse workspace. The existing jar file can have some different classes (than the workspace), so I can't simply do an 'export'. Is there any tool/plugin/easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Most archive managers can read .jar files (.jar is a type of .zip) and show you the contents

You'll still need to compile your code of course - Let me know if it works I never tried to drop in files like that to replace them.

If the .jar is signed you will have to sign it again afterwards.

Comment: I currently use the WinRAR for drop-in replacement (it works), but then it is very painful, if I have large no. of files scattered in the package hierarchy I have to visit many directories in the archive manager. I am in search of something like an eclipse plugin  which let me select the .class files from hierarchy (like Ctrl+Shft+R) and deploy them directly into the external jar file.

Comment: You can write your own eclipse plugin - it's a pain in the ass tho (you have to cast between classes a zillion times to do anything with the actual editor contents) but I've done it before

Answer (score 0):

You can modify .jar files using 7zip or WinRar (and probably a bunch of other archive managers). I'm a little unsure about class files, but I've used  it to change jsp and xslt-files. You just open the archieve, modify or replace a file, and it will ask you if you want to update the archieve itself..

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the jar utility :

> jar uf yourJarFile.jar files

Answer (score 0):

You can replace .class file using  Winrar utility n also you can use jar utility of java