# replace programmatic spring @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have some `proj_SDK.jar` which built with `Spring`. I have the sources of that `jar` so I see the following configuration class:

```
package com.my.private;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

/**
 * Configuration of Spring Beans file name.
 *
 */
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:base-core-beans.xml", "classpath:base-security-context.xml"})
public class XmlConfig
{

}
```

But the thing is that I don't want to load the `base-security-context.xml` context file. I would like to have only the `base-core-beans.xml` context.
What can I do load the `base-core-beans.xml` only?

Some (maybe) helpful details:
I'm building a web-application, so eventually I will also have `web.xml` file

Comment: What about `@ImportResource("classpath:base-core-beans.xml")` ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta - not working. I get an exception that tell bean about 2 bean definitions. I guess it loads them both. It could be useful in case where I'd like to add more beans of my own, but not in this case

Comment: I meant using @ImportResource("classpath:base-core-beans.xml") instead of full `@ImportResource({"classpath:base-core-beans.xml", "classpath:base-security-context.xml"})` not in addition ...

Comment: You might need to update the jar file with your own class file. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667153/updating-class-file-in-jar if you want to change the class file

Comment: how about fixing the source of the project instead of hacking away? Either that import is wrong or your use case is not really supported by the library right now. In both cases, you need to update that library.

Comment: @NareshVavilala and StéphaneNicoll - I'm getting the SKD.jar from maven. I don't have control over the sources. Hence, replacing files in the jar won't help as well

Comment: I guess you would just need to keep an empty base-security-context.xml  file in the classpath to make this work.

Comment: @NareshVavilala - that's what I've tried instantly. But for some reason, it didn't help. It's like it takes the old one first (loaded first to the classpath