# How to update .class file into existing .jar file?

Tags: java

Have one ".class" file and i want to update(add) new changes into the existing ".jar" file. 
How to do in "cmd" prompt(Windows OS) and what steps should be follow up the steps?

Comment: This is not a standard way to do it. But, jar files are just zip files with a different extension, so you can use a zip client to manipulate them. A more standard way to manipulate jar files is to use a tool like Ant - http://ant.apache.org/

Comment: You can use the jar command for this have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667153/updating-class-file-in-jar

Comment: What changes do you need to do? Add some extra files in the jar or change the compiled source code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the your jar file must be quite large and hence you are trying to avoid recreating it via Ant/Maven.

If you are using Java 7, visit this link : [Zip File System Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) ,

which treats a zip or jar file as file system and allows to update the jar, 
even though it's not via command line.