# Update Java files inside Jar that are already compiled into .class files

Tags: java, jar, antlr

I have a Jar file that uses a Java 1.5 grammar to parse Java code. The guy who coded it used a `Java.g` and a `JavaTreeParser.g` and ANTLR to generate these five files: `Java.tokens`, `JavaLexer.java`, `JavaParser.java`, `JavaTreeParser.java` and `JavaTreeParser.tokens`. These are the files that are executed in the application.

Now, I want to update those five files with the files that I generated using a Java grammar that supports version 1.8 of Java (and was developed by the same company, so the format follows the same patters).

I used the command `java -jar antlr-complete-3.5.2.jar Java.g JavaTreeParser.g` and it generated those five files.

Now I want to update the Jar with those files. I thought about using 7-zip to do so, but when I open the folder where those five files are supposed to be, `JavaLexer.java`, `JavaParser.java`, `JavaTreeParser.java` are "transformed" in a bunch `.class` files:

[image]

So, my question is: how can I replace these files in the Jar, since the ones in the Jar are already compiled into `.class` files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating .class file in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667153/updating-class-file-in-jar)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manually compile the generated .java-Files. If the code has any additional dependencies you can't provide (for example because they aren't provided in your original jar), try to create dummy classes that satisfy the dependencies at compile-time. You can then update your JAR-File either manually using 7-zip (e.g.) or with the following command:

```
$ jar uf <JAR-File> <files-to-update...>
```

e.g.:

```
$ jar uf myjar.jar Java.tokens JavaLever.class JavaParser.class JavaTreeParser.class JavaTreeParser.tokens
```