# Java Program to update .class file in jar file?

Tags: java, java-me, java-ee-6

I have jar demo1.jar . I want to replace one .class file [at com/example/demo2/ location] using java program .

path is like demo1.jar/BOOT-INF/classes/com/example/demo2/.

Comment: `ZipFile` may help you as JARs are ZIPs.

Comment: No ,Programmatically I want to do this . Using Java code .

Comment: Does using java jar considered java code ? :)

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667153/updating-class-file-in-jar

Comment: `ZipFile` is a java class that can be used for manipulating zip files.

Comment: Not Working . Thanks dan1st and Susan for reply . Susan I have checked that post and that is not working in my case. I simply replace the .class file in jar at path is like demo1.jar/BOOT-INF/classes/com/example/demo2/.

Comment: The duplink has code to do this kind of thing.  But note that you won't be able to reliably update a JAR that is on a running application's classpath.  You will either get file lock errors, or unpredictable behavior for the running app.

Comment: Hi Stephen , Actually I want replace the .class file of jar in one folder using command line or java code . Could you please help me with any link or command if you know. Thanks in advanced.